# When does my automatic 10-year UK visa ban end?

Tags: uk, visa-bans, criminal-records

I was in the UK in 2009 to participate in an event there. I went to London from 26 June until 11 September (long period) but I thought that was normal as I had a 6-month visa.

I went to South London Scout Centre and I stayed there until the start of the event on 1 August. I went to the event, stayed there for 10 day, and afterwards I rented room in London for one month.

On 11 September 2009, I was caught stealing at Sainsbury's Supermarket.

Does my 10-year ban end on the 1 January 2019, or on 11 September 2019?

Comment: Regardless of when your ban ends, your history will continue to have a negative impact on future visa applications.  Were you sentenced for the theft?  If not, on what grounds were you banned?

Comment: @phoog He might have been deported for criminal activity. His ban should end 10 years after the day he left the UK.

Comment: The visa you came in on only permitted certain activities, typically tourism.  I'm guessing you did not have a visa permitting criminal activity, or employment, which begs the question of *how you supported yourself* in one of the world's most expensive cities for 3 months. The facts suggest crime or employment (stealing things or jobs from Britons), and while they won't punish you for that again, they will presume that'll be your plan next time unless you show them otherwise.

Comment: Your ban will end when the decision was put in place, as indicted in the paperwork you received before or during your departure from the UK.

Comment: @Fethi Boukoftane Were you actually banned or are you hoping for a timeframe after which you don’t need to declare the crime in any visa application?

Comment: Another reason in favor of staying home on September 11. Nothing good ever happens on that day.

Comment: @Traveller it would always have to be referenced in a UK visa application.

Comment: @greatone which of the immigration rules is that?

Comment: @phoog Most foreign criminals who have been sentenced to prison are deported. http://www.aboutimmigration.co.uk/deportation-from-uk.html

Comment: @greatone yes, but the length of the ban depends on which specific rule it was issued under, as does the day from which the ban is.reckoned.  The rules I'm familiar with depend on the length of the sentence, and those rules count the ban from the end of the sentence.  I did not see a rule that counts the ban from the date of deportation, which is.why I asked which rule you were referring to.

Comment: @Harper: please don't be so quick to judge. I know tons of students that spent months in Europe (albeit not 6 months), or people that quit their job to travel abroad. You can find cheap accommodation (and South London Scouts Centre seems affordable) or live with friends/family/couch surfers. Once accommodation is taken care of, one can live a long time on his/her savings if temperate on his/her spendings. The OP may have had a job that allows him to work. Some people are simply very rich.

Comment: @taladris Ours is to say *how the government will view them*, so don't tell me not to be quick to judge. **Tell immigration**. Tell legislators to write softer laws.  6 months is a hard limit for most visas.  Working remotely for a homeland job is not allowed on most UK visas.  "Very rich" don't steal to eat. (why else does one steal groceries?)

Comment: @Harper: (1/2) it seemed to me it was your personal opinion ("I'm guessing you did not have a visa permitting criminal activity, or employment"). Nothing in the question said that the asker overstayed or tried to do so:  26 june - 11 september is far less than 6 months. Nothing said he was working remotely. There are many visas that allows one to work, and there are many ways, most of them legal, to fund one's trip abroad.

Comment: And there are many reasons to steal in a supermarket (though necessity is probably the main one): because it seems fun, because it seems easy, because one is bored, because one forgot his wallet, to "punish" the shopowner,... You have a lot of imagination concerning the OP, I am sure you can find many other reasons. Note that at no point, I am defending the OP of his crime: he stole, got caught and punished for that. That's fine and there is no need to add imaginary offenses (stealing jobs from Brittons???)

Answer (score 1):

As @greatone mentioned in the [comments](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118913/when-does-my-automatic-10-year-uk-visa-ban-end#comment291589_118913), the duration of the re-entry ban begins from the date you left the UK - in your case from 11 September 2009 or whenever you left the UK.

From [uk.gov](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules):

> V 3.10 The duration of a re-entry ban is as follows:
>   Duration of re entry ban from date they left the UK (...)
>
> ...
>
> (e) 10 years - was deported from the UK or was removed from the UK

Comment: If OP was caught stealing on September 11, 2009 there is no chance whatsoever that he was deported or removed on that day.  Furthermore, we don't know that OP was deported or removed.  Maybe he left voluntarily.

Comment: @phoog you are right thats almost imposible to be deported on the same day. But as the OP mentioned himselft a 10-year-ban, I assume that he/she was deported ot removed.

Comment: I wonder whether OP hasn't assumed that he is subject to a 10-year ban.  If he has paperwork informing him of the ban it should also explain how the ban is reckoned.

Answer (score 1):

> Does my 10-year ban end on the 1 January 2019, or on 11 September 2019?

No.  If you have a ten-year ban, it ends at some other time, unless you were deported on the day you were caught.

There is not enough information to answer your question, but we can offer some possibilities.

- If you were deported or removed from the UK, you have a 10-year ban from the date of the deportation or removal, as noted in Dirty-flow's [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/119158/19400).
- If you received a prison sentence that was at least 12 months long, but shorter than 4 years, you have a 10-year ban from the end of the sentence.  So, for example, if you were sentenced to a 47-month sentence beginning in 2010, and left the UK voluntarily after the end of the sentence, your ban ends in late 2023.

In both of these cases, the beginning of the ban will have been sometime *after* September 11, 2009, so in neither case will it be January 1, 2019 nor September 11, 2019.

If neither of those cases applies, you have a ban with a different duration.  For example, if your sentence was 4 years or longer, you have a permanent ban.  If your sentence was less than 12 months, you have a 5-year ban.  If you were removed "as a condition of a caution [under] the Criminal Justice Act 2003," you also have a 5-year ban.

The details are in [Appendix V of the visitor rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).